# C# frame method

Tags: c#

The frame method, which has two parameters, the frame length and height. The main program  lines i used

```
String s = Frame (5, 4);
Console.WriteLine (s);
```

which prints following:

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*****
```

this is very easy without method, but with method this seems to be difficult, any ideas?
This is my last question for today. :)

Comment: i'm not in school dude, i'm just want to learn c#

Comment: @csahrpnoobie - If you're trying to **learn** - don't ask for an answer without showing what you've already tried.... Having an answer handed to you won't help you learn half as well as **trying yourself before asking for advice** =)

Comment: Post the code for how to do it without a method. Writing it down will help you see how to do it with a method.

Comment: give some code that i can just start with it, i dont want full answer.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried so far? You're not going to have a lot of luck getting answers if you adopt a "just show me how" attitude. The users of this site are very helpful, but you've got to play the game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Sample {
    static string Frame(int width, int height){
        var wk = new List<string>();
        string term = new String('*', width);
        string inner = "*" + new String(' ', width-2) + "*";
        wk.Add(term);
        wk.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(inner, height-2));
        wk.Add(term);
        return String.Join("\n", wk);

    }
    static void Main(){
        string s = Frame (5, 4);
        Console.WriteLine (s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

think about using `StringBuilder` and a `for` loop inside your `Frame` implementation.
`StringBuilder` has a method to insert `n` times the same character.

Comment: @csharpnoobie - if you're going to be so insistent about people posting code then you could at least take the time to post what you've tried so far. This answer has enough information for you to make an initial attempt at writing the function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

We want a string with the characters in it. The [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) is a good tool for the job.

Let's break the box down, logically. When you think you have enough information to do this on your own, stop reading and give it a try.

We know we have a width, and a height, and a top and a bottom. The top and the bottom are solid lines of characters. We can create them easily like this:

```
var topOrBottom = new string('*', width);
```

And now we append that to our StringBuilder:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine(topOrBottom);
```

Now, we need to append lines for the left and right sides. We will do this height - 2 times. We subtract two because the top and bottom will be taken care of separately. As for the string we want to append, it's width - 2 spaces with a `*` on either side.

```
var side = string.Concat('*', new string(' ', width - 2), '*');
```

Put that in with a `for` loop, and you should have everything you need to do this, give it a shot. You can use `ToString()` on the StringBuilder to get a normal string out of it.

---

To complete the example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
{
    builder.AppendLine(side);
}
builder.AppendLine(topOrBottom);
```

Append the sides and the bottom.

A complete example might look something like this:

```
private static string Frame(int width, int height)
{
    if (width < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("width", width, "Width must be greater or equal to 2");
    }
    if (height < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("height", height, "Height must be greater or equal to 2");
    }
    var topOrBottom = new string('*', width);
    var side = string.Concat('*', new string(' ', width - 2), '*');
    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine(topOrBottom);
    for (var i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(side);
    }
    builder.AppendLine(topOrBottom);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```